# Upgrading Spring boot 2.0.9 to 2.3.12 gives errors

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, upgrade, spring-bean

I am trying to upgrade spring boot 2.0.9 to 2.3.12, but facing errors. I have followed spring boot release note and other github, https://docs.spring.io/-- dependencies and other websites as well and stuck with same errors. Why it is still not working?

Am I missing any dependencies? Cause I am getting error

> ->SEVERE: Exception invoking method manageApp java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]

Parent Pom:

```
<properties>
<fc.version>3.2.0</fc.version>
<org.springframework.version>5.2.15.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<revision>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Child Pom :

```
<properties>
<fc.version>
    3.2.0
</fc.version>
<gwtVersion>2.7.0</gwtVersion>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
<velocity.version>1.7</velocity.version>
<argLine> -Xmx512m </argLine>
<log4j2.version>2.17.0</log4j2.version>
<slf4j.version>1.7.32</slf4j.version>
<logback-version>1.2.7</logback-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
<artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
<version>0.8.0</version>
<classifier>runtime</classifier>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
<groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
<version>1.26</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<version>5.2.15.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
<version>6.1.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<version>2.11.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
<version>Hoxton.SR12</version>
<type>pom</type>
<scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
<version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
<type>pom</type>
<scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client</artifactId>
<version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
<version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions> 
</dependency>
<dependency>
<artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<version>5.3.9.RELEASE</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<version>5.3.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<version>5.3.9.RELEASE</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<version>5.3.9.RELEASE</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
<version>1.0.9.RELEASE</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
<artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
<version>0.7.0</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
<version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
<version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
<artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
<version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
<version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
<type>pom</type>
<scope>import</scope>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
<version>1.11.140</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-cbor</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
<artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
<version>1.61</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
<artifactId>bcpg-jdk15on</artifactId>
<version>1.61</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
<version>2.3.1</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
        <groupId>activation</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
<version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
<artifactId>activation</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
<version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
<artifactId>json</artifactId>
<version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
<version>2.30.1</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
<version>2.11.4</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
<version>2.11.4</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
<version>2.30.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-apache-client</artifactId>
<version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
<version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-io</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
<artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
<version>1.4.01</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
<artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
<version>4.5.13</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
<version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.uuid</groupId>
<artifactId>java-uuid-generator</artifactId>
<version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.commons.pool</artifactId>
<version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
<artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.fusesource.restygwt</groupId>
<artifactId>restygwt</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
<artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
<artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jackson</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
<version>2.11.4</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
<artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
<artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
<version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
<version>9.4.39.v20210325</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
<artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
<version>2.40.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
<artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.GA</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
<artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.GA</version>
<classifier>sources</classifier>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
<version>1.7.12</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi</artifactId>
<version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
<artifactId>jbpm-bpmn2</artifactId>
<version>6.5.0.Final</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
<artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
<version>1.4.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
<artifactId>stringtemplate</artifactId>
<version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
<artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
<version>3.5.2</version> 
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
<artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
<version>4.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
<artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
<version>${velocity.version}</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.concordion</groupId>
<artifactId>concordion</artifactId>
<version>1.4.2</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>ognl</groupId>
        <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>xom</groupId>
<artifactId>xom</artifactId>
<version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>xerces</groupId>
<artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
<version>2.12.0.SP03</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
<version>5.2.15.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
<version>4.3.30.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
<version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
<version>5.2.15.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>5.4.32.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
<artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
<version>6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
<version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
<artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
<version>${logback-version}</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
<artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
<version>${logback-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
<version>2.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
<version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
<artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
<version>2.0.9</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
<artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
<version>2.0.9</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
<artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
<version>3.27.0-GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.splunk.logging</groupId>
<artifactId>splunk-library-javalogging</artifactId>
<version>1.6.2</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>5.4.32.Final</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
<version>5.4.32.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
<version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>

<groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
<artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
<version>1.6.7</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
<version>19.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
<artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
<version>3.4.3</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
<artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
<version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
<artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
<artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
<version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
<artifactId>gson</artifactId>
<version>2.8.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
<version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
<version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
<version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.mikesamuel</groupId>
<artifactId>json-sanitizer</artifactId>
<version>1.2.2</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
<artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
<version>1.3.9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
<version>3.2.2</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
<version>1.8.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>cglib</groupId>
<artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
<version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
<version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Am I missing any dependencies? Cause I am getting error ->SEVERE: Exception invoking method manageApp
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]

Comment: A complete stack trace would be a good start.